# Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory

Tags: software-center, locale

I am new in Linux. I was trying to install wine and after /i followed instructions from a youtube video i got to the point where I needed to install wine from Ubuntu Software Center. The problem is the Ubuntu Software Center doesn't work anymore, it ask me to reparir it, and when I push the Repair button it gives me this error:

```
installArchives() failed: Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Please help me. Thank you :D

Comment: Try the following command in terminal and then retry the whole things:
sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score 4):

**Real solution** is here:

```
apt-get download libc-bin
dpkg -x libc-bin*.deb unpackdir/

sudo cp unpackdir/sbin/ldconfig /sbin/

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin
sudo apt-get install -f
```

enjoy! :)

Comment: This ended about 4 hours of work for me to try and upgrade my 14.04 lts server. Thank you very much.

Comment: I Love you! Thats it :D

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin
show...
libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.31-13+deb11u6 is to be installed

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get update
```

After this try re-installing [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

Comment: it gives me the same error after it asks me if I want to continue...

Answer (score 0):

Install the `libc-bin` package.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install libc-bin
```